# Restarting pc is stuck after installing Ubuntu on a isolated partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I have installed windows 10 and then went and installed Ubuntu but when the installation completes, I get the "restart now" option and upon clicking it everything just get stuck.

I tried hard restarting it but when the system loads up it immediately loads Windows. When I go in windows to the partitions I created especially for Ubuntu, I can see that they are no longer in "Unallocated" status, so it looks like it was installed or at least there is something there from the Ubuntu installation (not entirely sure).

There is no option for me to select which OS to load, can someone help please? I wasted so much time on this and went through every video and blog there is.

Comment: Are both installs UEFI (or both old BIOS/MBR)?  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI & https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi  Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Hi, I booted Ubuntu from the USB drive and I can see that it was booted in UEFI mode by searching for /sys/firmware/efi. Also, in windows the folder within the USB shows EFI if that makes any difference